# Can we extend a docker image using compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Dockerfile through which I have pulled an image from the docker registry and extended the image to modify some files in it.

Is there a way that I can extend the image from the compose file and use the image, instead of the pulling the image using Dockerfile and then customising it.

I want to use the compose file so that next time when I perform the compose up command,I can have the extended image ready for use.

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for configuring the docker images using Dockerfile based on the below reference link. It mentions to either created an extended image and upload it into the docker hub registery or extend it using the Dockerfile

https://dantehranian.wordpress.com/2015/03/25/how-should-i-get-application-configuration-into-my-docker-containers/

Thanks & Regards,